# Why do the voting arrow images on superuser.com have non-straight edges?

Tags: bug, status-completed, images

Does it look like this to anyone else?

*missing image*

Edit: I've edited the image to show the stackoverflow and superuser arrows next to each other. I'm not terribly concerned about the difference in size (although I think that could be the actual cause), but in the straightness of the diagonal edge.

After upvoting a question or answer on SuperUser, the up arrow

*missing image*

is kinda stretched, like this:

*missing image*

It's a small glitch, but it still annoys me.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: FYI: superuser.com != uservoice.com.  Please consider making sense in the future.

Comment: oops - slip of the brain :)

Comment: Woo! Is it possible to see where the merge came from?

Answer (score 4):

Viewing it in Opera, the slanted edges of the triangles do look more jagged/stepped on SU than they do on SF or SO. Kind of like a Lego roof where the tiles/bricks step vertical a tad before returning on its 30º (roughly) journey once more

Comment: Sounds like what I'm seeing - also in Internet Explorer 7.

Answer (score 2):

What annoyed me was when you go to a question with a scroll to a specific answer that you have voted up/down, the background is blue-ish and the arrow looks really cropped.

Answer (score 1):

The down vote image looks the same, it is likely by design.